# Displaying pandas dataframe after doing nbconvert for jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, pdf-generation, jupyter, nbconvert

When I run my notebook in Jupyter Notebook, I have a nice dataframe outputted. However, when I run my notebook from command line and convert it to a pdf using `--to pdf` the dataframe does not display. Is there anything I can do to display the dataframe or does nbconvert to pdf not allow that? I also ran a styler to color cells in my dataframe so the only output that shows up in the pdf for the dataframe is `<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler at 0x11852eef0>`. Would love suggestions on alternate methods to display the dataframe. Thanks!